# Eevee - Duplicated lights not appearing in render / Lights that once appeared are gone

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

A bit of desperate situation, I've got a pretty large night-time scene that I've been working on for the past 3 weeks. Recently I noticed that a light that I placed as the moon early on, is no longer rendering. I've also created multiple street lamp meshes with lights placed in them, however only a handful of lights appear in the render.

I've found that this is a common issue with 2.81, so I updated my OS and upgraded to 2.82 with absolutely no luck. I found that I can open the project in 2.80 and render it correctly, however that version won't let me apply changes to the scene, so I've had to flip back and forth from 2.82 to 2.80.

Does anyone know a workaround for this in 2.81 or 2.82?

Comment: There is a limit on the number of lamps EEVEE can fit in the GPU for rendering, there was also a limitation that didn't allow rendering shadows from lamps inside duplicators in 2.80

Comment: can you make some of the lights, in the back ground be emission shaders on the mesh?

Comment: Thanks Duarte, I actually found out about the limit shortly after posting this, and that seems to be what the problem was.

Comment: I originally tried to use emission meshes for the lights, however I had to switch to lamps because I wasn't able to see the light casting onto my floor mesh when I had a top-down view of the light pole, and I used 4 lights per pole because that's how the lamps I based these on are irl, so it's understandable that I had this issue now that I know there's a limit